# Eposh time not converting date/format in c program

Tags: epoch

I have been working on this code where I read a binary file and convert it into readable texts. I pretty much got it done for the most part except the epoch time. I tried playing around with some coding but I still can't get it to work. Right now with the way I have the program coded, the first line would print like this 
YV2827 kCLT KSRQ 1389396780 (Eposh time)
wed dec 31 19:00:00 1969 (which is NOT 1389396780). Can some one help me out why it's not printing out the proper date/time?

```
 <i>#include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <time.h>


 typedef struct {

 char flightNum[7]; // +1 due to null
 char originAirport[5];
 char destAirport[5];
 long time;
}FLIGHTDATA;


// function for flight number
void fofflightNum(FLIGHTDATA*);

int main() {
int i = 0;
time_t c;

FLIGHTDATA flights[30000];

FILE* binfile;

binfile = fopen("acars.bin", "rb");

if(binfile == NULL) {
    printf("sorry, can't open!\n");
    exit(-1);
    }

while (!feof(binfile))  {
fgets(&flights[i].flightNum, 7, binfile);
fseek(binfile, 1, SEEK_CUR);
fgets(&flights[i].originAirport, 5, binfile);
fseek(binfile, 1, SEEK_CUR);
fgets(&flights[i].destAirport, 5, binfile);
fseek(binfile, 4, SEEK_CUR);
fread(&flights[i].time, 1, sizeof(long), binfile);


c = strtoul( "flights[i].time", NULL, 0 );
ctime( &c );

printf("%s %s %s %ld\n", flights[i].flightNum, flights[i].originAirport,   
flights[i].destAirport, flights[i].time);
i++;
printf("%s", ctime( &c ));


system("Pause");
}



fclose(binfile);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally solve it, the correct coding is

```
c = flights[i].time;
ctime( &c );
```